# iOS - UICollectionView shadow flickers while reloading the cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

In my collection view I have added a custom view with shadow in the collection cell.

I added shadow to the view by using the following code.

```
    cell.shadowView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    cell.shadowView.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
    cell.shadowView.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
    cell.shadowView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(-2.0f, 2.0f);
    cell.shadowView.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0f;
    cell.shadowView.layer.shadowRadius = 4.0f;
    cell.shadowView.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;
    cell.shadowView.layer.rasterizationScale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
```

Whenever I reload the cell the reloaded cell flickers every time. 
Following code I used for reloading the cell.

```
    [self.collectionView performBatchUpdates:^{
        NSIndexPath* indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1 inSection:0];
        NSArray* indexPathArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:indexPath, nil];
        [self.collectionView reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:indexPathArray];

    } completion:nil];
```

I want to avoid this flickering when reloading the cell.

I can avoid the flickering by running the **performBatchUpdates** call inside **[UIView performWithoutAnimation:^{}]** animation block. But it causes breakage in the existing animation code.

Is there any way to avoid this flickering issue?

Thank you.